# How do I stop MATLAB from displaying the entire contents of a .m file when it runs?

Tags: matlab

I have a small .m file which I am running in MATLAB R2010b by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> in the Editor. Here's the file:

```
clear all, close all, clc;
%why are you printing !?
a = 1
c = eye(5);
```

I would expect this code to display the following when I run it:

```
a =

     1
```

But instead it displays this:

```
%why are you printing !?
a = 1

a =

     1

c = eye(5);
```

The same behavior happens if I call the file from the console. I can't find anything on the internet or in the console settings in MATLAB to change this. I have used many different versions of MATLAB and this has never happened before.

Comment: I'm on R2010a; I copy-pasted your code into an m-file and ran it with F5. It printed `a = 1` to the console. Have you changed a MATLAB config setting? (Alternately, have you tried closing MATLAB and restarting it?)

Comment: Also, a friendly warning: `clear all, close all, clc` is OK for scripts you are never going to distribute, but don't use it in code you share for the use of others. It would make me very unhappy if I was working on some data and your script erased it without asking.

Comment: This is purely personal code, but thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You appear to have inadvertently turned on [command echoing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/echo.html). Type this in your Command Window to turn it off:

```
>> echo off
```

Comment: Thanks!  I must have run a script which had this command as I didn't know it existed and am on a brand new install of Matlab.

Comment: I am suddenly transported back to using a DOS command line in 1994. Thanks for the nostalgia trip, @gnovice! (More seriously, I forgot that MATLAB even had this option.)